# What happens when you verify a detached signature?

Tags: gpg

I'm trying to understand what happens when verifying a detached gpg signature.

Here's an example from the gnupg [manual](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html):

```
blake% gpg --verify doc.sig doc
gpg: Signature made Fri Jun  4 12:38:46 1999 CDT using DSA key ID BB7576AC
gpg: Good signature from "Alice (Judge) <alice@cyb.org>"
```

How does gpg determine that the signature is a good one? Does the signature contain a hash of the file which was signed? If so, how do you extract that hash from the signature itself?

I tried `gpg --list-packets <signature>` but it doesn't seem to show full information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `--list-packets` option to get a dump of what's in a gpg file. The description of the file format is [RFC 4880](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4880) (OpenPGP standard).

The signature does not directly contain a hash. It contains information that allows verifying both the hash and the sender: there is a *signature verification algorithm*, which takes a hash value and a public key as input, and returns *yes* or *no*; the algorithm returns *yes* if the signature was made by the private key corresponding to the given public key from a message with the given private key, and returns *no* in all other circumstances (signature of a different hash, signature made by a different key, or a bunch of bytes that can't be a signature at all). Under the [DSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) algorithm, I think it's infeasible to extract the hash from a signature if you don't have the private key.

The signature file contains the identity of the signer as well as the signature value. To verify the signature, gpg reads the signer's public key from your keyring, calculates the hash of the data, and applies the signature verification algorithm.

Comment: I missed the DSA link on a first read, but that shows details of the signature verification algorithm.  I had wrongly imagined I could coerce gpg to show me the hash from the signature alone.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ gpg --list-packets myfile.asc
[...]
       digest algo 10, begin of digest 77 dd
```

This shows you which digest algorithm was used. Unfortunately neither the man page nor `gpg --version` tell us which algorithm is assigned to which ID. We need to dive into the RFC of the packet format to find this information: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-9.4

```
ID           Algorithm                             Text Name
--           ---------                             ---------
1          - MD5 [HAC]                             "MD5"
2          - SHA-1 [FIPS180]                       "SHA1"
3          - RIPE-MD/160 [HAC]                     "RIPEMD160"
4          - Reserved
5          - Reserved
6          - Reserved
7          - Reserved
8          - SHA256 [FIPS180]                      "SHA256"
9          - SHA384 [FIPS180]                      "SHA384"
10         - SHA512 [FIPS180]                      "SHA512"
11         - SHA224 [FIPS180]                      "SHA224"
100 to 110 - Private/Experimental algorithm
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, digital signatures are usually secure hashes, which are signed by the secret key of the signer.

Signing the whole message is a lot more slow and not more secure. Additionally the algorithm should take care of the length of blocks, padding (in a manner not to disclose too much information), etc.

Note: also on asymmetric encryption, for speed reason, only a ephemeral symmetric key is asymmetric encrypted, and the rest of message is just symmetrical encrypted.

Comment: Can you use gpg to see the hash embedded in the signature?

Comment: Digital signatures are *always* signatures of hashes. Signing the whole message doesn't work in general, because there's a (fairly low) limit to the size of what you can sign with any of the asymmetric signature algorithms. Unlike encryption, padding doesn't come up: all common hash algorithms can cope with an arbitrary number of bytes.